# Athena ignore LIMIT in some queries

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have a table with a lot of partitions (something that we're working on reducing)

When I query :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10
```

I get :

> "HIVE_EXCEEDED_PARTITION_LIMIT: Query over table 'mytable' can potentially read more than 1000000 partitions"

Why isn't the "LIMIT 10" part of the query sufficient for Athena to return a result without reading more that 1 or 3 partitions ?

ANSWER :
During the query planing phase, Athena attempts to list all partitions potentially needed to answer the query.
Since Athena doesn't know which partitions actually contain data (not empty partitions) it will add all partitions to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena plans a query and then executes it. During planning it lists the partitions and all the files in those partitions. However, it does not know anything about the files, how many records they contain, etc.

When you say `LIMIT 10` you're telling Athena you want at most 10 records in the result, and since you don't have any grouping or ordering you want 10 arbitrary records.

However, during the planning phase Athena can't know which partitions have files in them, and how many of those files it will need to read to find 10 records. Without listing the partition locations it can't know they're not all empty, and without reading the files it can't know they're not all empty too.

Therefore Athena first has to get the list of partitions, then list each partition's location on S3, even if you say you only want 10 arbitrary records.

In this case there are so many partitions that Athena short-circuits and says that you probably didn't mean to run this kind of query. If the table had fewer partitions Athena would execute the query and each worker would read as little as possible to return 10 records and then stop – but each worker would produce 10 records, because the worker can't assume that other workers would return any records. Finally the coordinator will pick the 10 records out of all the results form all workers to return as the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Limit works on the display operation only, if I am not wrong. So query will still read everything but only display 10 records.
Try to limit data using where condition, that should solve the issue

Comment: I think that's unlikely, it would be extremely inefficient if the query would read all data and then only return the first 10 records. What's more likely is that the query planner can't reliably determine how many partitions would need to be read to satisfy the query and thus raises this message.

Comment: @NNM can you provide any source for this information ("limit works only on display") ? I didn't found that information in the AWS doc. Also suggesting to use a where condition is besides the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think Athena's workers try to read max number of the partitions (relative to the partition size of the table) to get that random chunk of data and stop when query is fulfilled (which in your case, is the specification of the limit).

In your case, it's not even starting to execute the above process because of too many partitions involved. Therefore, if Athena is not planning your random data selection query, you have to explicitly plan it and hand it over to the execution engine.

Something like:

```sql
select * from mytable 
where (
   partition_column in (
      select partition_column from mytable limit cast(10 * rand() as integer)
   )
)
limit 100
```